# Answer your question copying an answer and mark yours as accepted

Tags: discussion, support

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742312/add-texture-to-unlit-transparent-color-shader?answertab=oldest#tab-top) question and as you can see the OP replied the question using xyLe_'s answer and marking it as accepted.

I don't know the legality of this practice. I know that is acceptable doing it when the answer is a comment (I read the thread on Meta). However, this time the time difference is over 4h (after xyLe_'s edit).

What do you think?

Comment: What is wrong in answering my own question by getting pointers from xyLe_'s answer. I answered my own question with exact solution so late users can get help from it instead of going through several link and then waste time in experiments. I gave credit to xyLe_ in my answer though.

Comment: Perfectly acceptable, only a very slight oops on the attribution.  The OP even respected the poster's preference by not rolling back his edit.  The meta effect is a very ugly beast here, please stop downvoting.

Comment: *meta-effect* turns out to be *knee-jerk reaction* in such cases.

Comment: Strangely in these situations I have a habbit of editing the answer, and asking the poster to make sure they are happy with the edit so as I can then accept their answer.

Comment: Anyway the positive votes show it all. I don't have anything else to say.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The OP most likely answered the question with the copied content from the other answer because it was was edited out of that answer. Also since proper attribution was provided, there is no issue with the content being copied from the other answer.

Comment: Even if there is a proper attribution you still need the approval of the owner.

Comment: @Enzokie No. All content posted to Stack Exchange is under CC licenses. Attribution is enough, the approval is given by the author by submitting it to SE.

Comment: It would be nice to know (possibly through a **+1** aside within the attribution) that the original content was marked helpful.